# Return 0 quantity when SKU not found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have in my database 2 tables: `warehouse` and `warehouse_inventory`.

My `warehouse` table looks like:

```
 name   | warehouse_id   | 
--------+----------------|
 name_1 | warehouse_id_1 |
 name_2 | warehouse_id_2 |
 name_3 | warehouse_id_3 |
```

My `warehouse_inventory` table looks like:

```
 warehouse_id   | SKU         | quantity |         
----------------+-------------+----------|
 warehouse_id_1 | item_sku_1  | 100      |
 warehouse_id_2 | item_sku_1  | 100      |
```

And now, I am looking for a solution which gets me result like this:

```
 name   | warehouse_id   | SKU        | quantity |
--------+-----------------------------+----------|
 name_1 | warehouse_id_1 | item_sku_1 | 100      |
 name_1 | warehouse_id_1 | item_sku_2 | 0        |
 name_2 | warehouse_id_2 | item_sku_1 | 100      |
 name_2 | warehouse_id_2 | item_sku_2 | 0        |
 name_3 | warehouse_id_3 | item_sku_1 | 0        |
 name_3 | warehouse_id_3 | item_sku_2 | 0        |
```

when I select with `where` condition in SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM [what's here?] WHERE warehouse_inventory.SKU IN ('item_sku_1', 'item_sku_2')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this if you don't have a table with all the SKU you have on your database.

So, assuming that you have a table called [item] for all your item master data, you should do that:

```
SELECT W0.name, W0.warehouse_id, I0.SKU, ISNULL(W1.quatity, 0) as 'Quantity'
FROM [item] I0
CROSS JOIN [warehouse] W0
LEFT JOIN [warehouse_inventory] W1 ON W1.warehouse_id = W0.warehouse_id AND W1.SKU = I0.SKU
```

On SAP Business One we do this:

```
SELECT W0.WhsName, W0.WhsCode, I0.ItemCode, ISNULL(W1.OnHand, 0) as 'Quantity'
FROM OITM I0
CROSS JOIN OWHS W0
LEFT JOIN OITW W1 ON W1.WhsCode = W0.WhsCode AND W1.ItemCode = I0.ItemCode
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: All SKUs are in my `warehouse_inventory` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select w.name, w.warehouse_id, wii.SKU, coalesce(i.quantity, 0) as quantity 
from warehouse w cross join 
     warehouse_inventory wii left join
     warehouse_inventory i 
     on i.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id and i.SKU = wii.SKU
order by w.name;
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that is a good direction, but does not work as I expected.

`select w.name, w.warehouse_id, wii.SKU, coalesce(i.quantity, 0) as quantity 
from warehouse w cross join 
     warehouse_inventory wii left join
     warehouse_inventory i 
     on i.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id and i.SKU = wii.SKU
where i.SKU in ('item_sku_2')
order by w.name;`

returns nothing